# How do select a string greater then 8k characters out of a SQL Server 2008 XML field

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, adodb

I am building a small php application that simply extracts an XML string out of a database and displays the entire string on a page inside a textarea. Sounds simple, right? When i do this, i hit an 8k character limit and my XML is truncated.

All i want to do is get the raw text out of a XML field.

SQL Server 2008 does not allow cast or convert to text. When I convert to `nvarchar(max)`, I get a little more then without converting, but it's still truncated.  Using the GUI, I can select the field and open it to reveal all the text....how do you do this programmatically?

I am using ADODBPHP

```
$sql = "SELECT [IndicatorID]
              ,[LitpMultiYearXml]
              ,[LitpComparisonXml]
          FROM [MD_SPP_0910].[dbo].[SppResult] 
         where IndicatorID = ".$_GET['indicator_id'];

$xml = $db->GetRow($sql);
//echo $sql;
$multi_year = $xml[1];
$multi_year = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(">",">\n",$multi_year));

echo "<textarea name='xml' cols='80' rows='20'>$multi_year</textarea><input type='hidden' name='indicator_id' value='$indicator_id'/>";
```

Comment: Is the `LitpMultiYearXml` column contain only the value you want, or is there XML markup in it?  If it's the later, you could use [TSQL's XML.value function](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/shred-xml-data-with-xquery-in-sql-server-2005/6140404)

Comment: Is this *really* an XML-typed column? Or just a char column with some XML text in it?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I want all the XML markup along with values...

Comment: You could try a cast to varchar(max) first and then to text. `cast(cast(XMLCol as varchar(max)) as text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You could try a cast to varchar(max)
>   first and then to text.
>   cast(cast(XMLCol as varchar(max)) as
>   text) – Mikael Eriksson

This was Correct!

i thought the inner cast would limit it, but i was wrong!